# How to solve ChunkLoadError: Loading hot update chunk second_app failed in webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

while setup a new project for development, the app is not hot reloading. The app consists of multiple apps separated in its different folders.Currently, there are 2 apps `html_nodes_prototype` and `second_app` in `src/apps` folder. Each app consist of `index.html`, `style.css` and `main.js` when I visit the link     `http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.html`, the app shows but If I change something in `src/apps/second_app/main.js`. It doesn't hot reload, I've to manually reload to get changes. I've set up a webpack-dev-server. Error prompts in the console. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the config file.

**Error in console**

```
[HMR] Update failed: ChunkLoadError: Loading hot update chunk second_app failed.
(missing: http://localhost:8080/second_app.5b0047c2bf2b48c8a084.hot-update.js)
    at http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:987:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at loadUpdateChunk (http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:982:20)
    at http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:1411:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.hmrC.jsonp (http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:1406:22)
    at http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:819:45
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:8080/second_app/second_app.bundle.js:815:53
```

**paths.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // Source files
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),

  // Production build files
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),

  // public path
  public: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/"),
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const common = require("./webpack.common");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const merge = require("webpack-merge").merge;
const paths = require("./paths");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",

  output: {
    filename: "[name]/[name].bundle.js",
    path: paths.build,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
    ],
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // contentBase: paths.build,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 8080,
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "html_nodes_prototype/html_nodes_prototype.html",
      title: "HTML Nodes",
      template: "src/apps/html_nodes_prototype/index.html",
      chunks: ["html_nodes_prototype", "vendor"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "second_app/second_app.html",
      title: "Second app",
      hot: true,
      template: "src/apps/second_app/index.html",
      chunks: ["second_app", "vendor"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const paths = require("./paths");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",

  entry: {
    html_nodes_prototype: paths.src + "/apps/html_nodes_prototype/main.js",
    second_app: paths.src + "/apps/second_app/main.js",
    vendor: paths.src + "/apps/_vendor/vendor.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.m?js$/, use: ["babel-loader"] }],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Adding `runtimeChunk: 'single'` to webpack.dev.js works for me. Found the answer [here](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/issues/88#issuecomment-627558799)

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single'
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: it`s work but when finish hot reload the component state is 'reloaded' and  state is cleared :/

Comment: Sweet upvote for @Sameer . It seems that HtmlWebpackPlugin kinda force compile twice least for me that's running e.g. npx webpack serve using webpack-dev-server . Once I included suggest snippet by Sameer , all files started reloading properly . Life saver , thanks !

Comment: @LuanLuanLuan you must use `devServer: {devMiddleware: {writeToDisk : true}}` to stay persisted for your data . It's achievable since Webpack v5 . For more please refer to [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware)

Comment: @Sameer Thanks for this solution and the accompanying issue link.

Comment: This worked great for me!  I found this solution after getting the error on my console: `HMR Update failed: ChunkLoadError: Loading hot update chunk bundle failed`.     Thank you!!!